# Sql Compact: Querying an Ntext column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I recently changed a column from nvarchar(4000) to ntext. Afterwards I'm getting an 'The ntext and image data types cannot be used in WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY, ON, or IN clauses, except when these data types are used with the LIKE or IS NULL predicates.' exception off a basic query like this:

select BLAH FROM Table WHERE Text = @Text

Is this an issue with Sql Compact 3.5? I have updated to 3.5 SP2 because I saw that this was an issue with LINQ queryies, but I didn't know it was an issue with normal queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this in SQL CE 3.5 is to have a nvarchar(4000) in addition to an NText. You can work on the first 4000 characters of the string for searching, sorting, preview etc - but you cannot both try to store an arbitrary length of data (ntext) is a limited device, yet expect it to also have good support for varchar-supported operations on the same column.  At least not until later version of SQL CE when devices are more powerful.

Comment: I'm going to try and use this in a solution to the problem. Thanks kiwi.

Answer (score 0):

This is not just SQLCE, the same goes for normal SQL server too.